# Integral limit as $N\to\infty$ in Theorem 8.15 of Gilbarg-Trudinger

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am reviewing the proof of Theorem 8.15 in Gilbarg-Trudinger (see below).

In equation (8.36), how can we take $N\to\infty$? Writing $2^* := \frac{2\hat{n}}{\hat{n}-2}$ and $q^\ast := \frac{2q}{q-2}$, equation (8.36) is presicely
$$
\left(\int_{w \le N}\left(w^\beta - k^\beta\right)^{2^\ast} + \int_{w > N}\left(\beta N^{\beta-1}w - \beta N^\beta +N^\beta-k^\beta\right)^{2^\ast}\right)^{1/2^\ast} \le C\left(\int_{w \le N}\left(\beta w^{\beta}\right)^{q^\ast} + \int_{w > N}\left(\beta N^{\beta-1}w\right)^{q^\ast}\right)^{1/q^\ast}.
$$
By the monotone convergence theorem, I can easily handle the integrals over $w \ge N$. Clearly, since $w\in L^{2^\ast}$ we also have $w\in L^{q^\ast}$; so $\int_{w> N} w^{q^\ast} \to 0$ as $N\to\infty$. However, I do not know whether
$$
\int_{w > N}\left(\beta N^{\beta-1}w\right)^{q^\ast} \to 0
$$
as $N\to\infty$ due to the multiple $N^{(\beta-1)q^\ast}$.

Any advice on how to handle this integral (as well as the integral $\int_{w > N}\left(\beta N^{\beta-1}w - \beta N^\beta +N^\beta-k^\beta\right)^{2^\ast}$) would be appeciated. I thought of trying to combine them but I am not sure how to do that either.

[image]

[image]

Equation 8.3

\begin{equation}
    Lu=D_i(a^{ij}(x)D_ju+b^i(x)u)+c^i(x)D_iu+d(x)u
\end{equation}.

Equation 8.29
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        A^i(x,z,p) &= a^{ij}(x)p_j + b^i(x)z - f^i(x),\\
        B(x,z,p) &= c^i(x)p_i + d(x)z - g(x)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Equation 8.30 For $v\ge 0, v\in C_0^1(\Omega)$

\begin{equation}
     \int_{\Omega}\left(D_ivA^i(x,u,Du)-vB(x,u,Du)\right)dx \le(\ge,=)0
 \end{equation}

Equation 8.32

\begin{equation}
    \bar z=|z|+k,\qquad \bar b=\lambda^{-2}(|b|^2+|c|^2+k^{-2}|f|^2)+\lambda^{-1}(|d|+k^{-1}|g|)
\end{equation}

Equation 8.33

\begin{align}
p_iA^i(x,z,p)  & \ge \frac{\lambda}{2}(|p|^2-2\bar b\bar z^2)  \\
      | \bar zB(x,z,p)  |     &\le \frac{\lambda}{2}\left( \epsilon|p|^2+\frac{\bar b}{\epsilon}\bar z^2\right) 
\end{align}

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a little silly but I'll leave my answer here anyway.

If we don't split the integral between where $w \ge N$ and $w<N$, we can just apply the monotone convergence theorem to
$$
f_N(x) = \left[\mathbb{1}_{w\le N}\left(w^\beta - k^\beta\right) + \mathbb{1}_{w>N}\left(\beta N^{\beta-1}w - \beta N^\beta + N^\beta - k^\beta\right)\right]^{2^{\ast}}.
$$
Indeed, $(f_N)$ is an increasing sequence of non-negative functions converging pointwise to $\left(w^\beta - k^\beta\right)^{2^\ast}$.

Same idea on the right-hand side.